# StringBuilder's appendFormat_5 not able to parse the positional params

Tags: vbscript, stringbuilder, hp-uft

I'm getting below issue while running a testscript from Unified Functional testing tool.

I used System.Text.StringBuilder Class's method AppendFormat_5 to format the string with predefined positional arguements injected by UFT tool.

I tried debugging with VbsEditor and its working fine.
But getting error if i run it through UFT.
I would like know possible reasons that could cause this issue so that i could get more pointers to debug this error.

code:

```
dim vParam1, vParam2, vParam3, vParam4, vParam5
vParam1 = "12345"
vParam2 = "123"
vParam3 = ""
vParam4 = ""
vParam5 = ""
sFormatString = "a - {0} - b - {1}"

Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
sb.AppendFormat_5 Nothing,sFormatString, Array(vParam1, vParam2, vParam3, vParam4, vParam5) 
MsgBox sb.toString
```

sb.toString method is returning "a - System.Object[]"

Comment: What happens if you declare your sb and sFormatString variables with `Dim sb, sFormatString`; call `sb.AppendFormat_4` instead, without the first (Nothing) argument; and call `MsgBox sb.toString()` with parenthesis, since it's a method, not an object property?

Comment: Also, maybe try explicitly converting each Array param as a variant of sub-type string.  For example, `sb.AppendFormat_4 sFormatString, Array(CStr(vParam1), CStr(vParam2), CStr(vParam3), CStr(vParam4), CStr(vParam5))`

Comment: @leeharvey1 thank you very much for pointers. ur first suggestion worked at first attempt itself. thanks again.